# Soap UI mock service

Tags: soapui

I work on a migration-integration project where the integration layer is getting migrated to BPM. Here I need to mock the Integration (Mediation) Layer ie the BPM layer.

I need to know if it is possible to do such mocking. If so, is it feasible through SOAP UI?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create mock services in SoapUI, it's easy and efficient as SoapUI generates most from the given WSDL (or WADL).

With Groovy scripting you can dynamically create mock responses depending on the service request or other parameters. You can pass data from the service request to the mock response and do many other things to simulate real services.

You can also have a set of mock responses and choose one of them according to your request.

Once you create the services in SoapUI user environment, you can export them as WAR and deploy to any application server (e.g. JBoss).

Answer (score 0):

Mocking with SoapUI will start a Jetty server listening on a specified port with either REST or SOAP services. The response can be based on request content and you can run scripts in Groovy on several phases of the execution, which enables an almost unlimited extension of the tool.

Read more: http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/mock-services.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do this using SOAP UI. Below are the steps to create MOCK service for SOAP WS. You may follow this for further reference [how-to-build-soap-mock-service-using](http://hpwc3po.blogspot.com/2019/10/how-to-build-soap-mock-service-using.html).

1. Right click on the interface of SOAP project and go to Generate SOAP Mock Service
2. Define your variables and Click OK
3. Define your MOCK response and Start MOCK service
4. Trigger request and check MOCK logs